# looping in XSLT - <xsl:for-each

Tags: xslt, foreach, navigation, umbraco

I need to render the following format in XSLT. I have a `<xsl:for-each` loop with 5 elements  (Text1, Text2... Text5) and need to wrap an ul tag after every three elements. Any suggestions please?

```
<ul>
    <li>Text1</li>
    <li>Text2</li>
    <li>Text3</li>
</uL>
<ul>
    <li>Text4</li>
    <li>Text5</li>
</uL>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question, +1.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="thing[position() mod 3 = 1]">
  <ul>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGrpoup" select=
    ".|following-sibling::*[not(position() > 2)]"/>
  </ul>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="thing" mode="inGrpoup">
  <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document**:

```
<things>
    <thing>1</thing>
    <thing>2</thing>
    <thing>3</thing>
    <thing>4</thing>
    <thing>5</thing>
    <thing>6</thing>
    <thing>7</thing>
    <thing>8</thing>
</things>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result** (things in groups of consecutive three):

```
<ul>
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>4</li>
   <li>5</li>
   <li>6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
   <li>7</li>
   <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Template pattern matching** the first `thing` of a group of three `thing` elements.
2. **Using modes** to process a group of `thing` elements (in a different way than the processing of the initial starting `thing`), once determined.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting question.  I've outlined one solution below, that uses an `<xsl:key>` to identify each group of three, using a little modular arithmetic.

Input document:

```
<TestDocument>
    <Element>Alpha</Element>
    <Element>Bravo</Element>
    <Element>Charlie</Element>
    <Element>Delta</Element>
    <Element>Echo</Element>
    <Element>Foxtrot</Element>
    <Element>Golf</Element>
    <Element>Hotel</Element>
</TestDocument>
```

Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <!-- Declare a key to identify each group of 3 elements -->
    <xsl:key name="positionKey" match="/TestDocument/Element" use="floor((position() - 2) div 3)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/TestDocument">
        <html>
            <!-- Iterate over the first element in each group -->
            <xsl:for-each select="Element[(position() - 1) mod 3 = 0]">
                <ul>
                    <!-- Grab all elements from this group -->
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('positionKey', position()-1)"/>
                </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Element">
        <li><xsl:value-of select="."/></li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results:

```
<html>
    <ul>
        <li>Alpha</li>
        <li>Bravo</li>
        <li>Charlie</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Delta</li>
        <li>Echo</li>
        <li>Foxtrot</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>Golf</li>
        <li>Hotel</li>
    </ul>
</html>
```